# CSS no funciona en mi segundo div cordova

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo estos 2 `div` en mi `body` y son los únicos que tengo.

El primero muestra unas tablas. El segundo tiene un formulario y debe mostrarse cuando haga **clic** en una de las tablas. Al hacer clic sobre una tabla del primer `div` estas convocan una función que oculta el `div` con `id="pagina1"` y muestra el `div` con `id="pagina2"`, es decir usando el comando `$("#pagina1").hide()` y `$("#pagina2").show()`.

El problema es que por alguna razón **css** no funciona en los 2 `div`, mas bien solo funciona en el primer `div` que este declarado.

```
<div data-role="page" id="pagina1">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>LISTADO DE REMITOS PENDIENTES </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="idResultado"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="pagina2">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Registro de Remito </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="titlepage">Ingrese los datos </div>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <input type="text" id="txtCodRemito" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Codigo Remito" required />
                <input type="datetime-local" id="txtfecha" name="birthdaytime">
                <select id="cbProveedor">
                    <option value="-1">Seleccione un Proveedor</option>
                </select>
                <select id="cbCombustible">
                    <option value="A">Seleccione un Combustible</option>
                    <option value="B">Debe Seleccionar un proveedor para cargar los combustibles</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="txtLitros" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Litros Cargados" required />
                <input type="text" id="txtMonto" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Monto Total" required />
                <button id="btnCamara">Foto de Remito</button>
                <div style="border: 1px solid; width: 200px; min-height:100px; margin: 0 auto;">
                    <img src="" id="myImage" />
                </div>
                <button id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</button>
            </div>
            <div id="idResultado"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Y el css?  No sabremos ayudarte si no vemos lo que pone alli, pues quizas el problema esté alli y no en el html

Answer (score 0):

No veo el código pero si veo que tienes repetido un id, btnRegistrar. Si ese es un botón que usas para llamar a los métodos hide y show vas a tener problemas, y puede ser la causa del error.
Mira esta copia de tu código con un texto donde pulsar para llamar a los métodos y ver que si funcionan.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="pagina1">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>LISTADO DE REMITOS PENDIENTES </h1>
        </div>
            <div data-role="content">
            <div id="idResultado">Click para ocultar est y mostrar pagina2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="pagina2">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Registro de Remito </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="titlepage">Ingrese los datos </div>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <input type="text" id="txtCodRemito" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Codigo Remito" required />
                <input type="datetime-local" id="txtfecha" name="birthdaytime">
                <select id="cbProveedor">
                    <option value="-1">Seleccione un Proveedor</option>
                </select>
                <select id="cbCombustible">
                    <option value="A">Seleccione un Combustible</option>
                    <option value="B">Debe Seleccionar un proveedor para cargar los combustibles</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" id="txtLitros" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Litros Cargados" required />
                <input type="text" id="txtMonto" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Monto Total" required />
                <button id="btnCamara">Foto de Remito</button>
                <div style="border: 1px solid; width: 200px; min-height:100px; margin: 0 auto;">
                    <img src="" id="myImage" />
                </div>
                <button id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</button>
            </div>
            <div id="idResultado">Click para ocultar esta pagina y mostrar pagina1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
$('#idResultado').click(ocultar);
function ocultar()
  {
     $('#pagina1').hide();  
     $('#pagina2').show();  
  }
$('#idResultado2').click(ocultar2);
function ocultar2()
  {
     $('#pagina2').hide();  
     $('#pagina1').show();  
  }
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, le quiete el atributo data-role="page" a los 2 div y los a ambos de otro div y a ese div le puse el atributo data-role="page", ahora si funciona